# How to profile WebGL with ext_disjoint_timer_query extension?

Tags: webgl, profiling, gpu, webgl-extensions

In WebGL we have special extension [EXT_disjoint_timer_query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_disjoint_timer_query) for proper GPU profiling, but I can't find good manual how to use it. For example initialization below works in my machine

```
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
let ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_disjoint_timer_query');
let startQuery = ext.createQueryEXT();
ext.queryCounterEXT(startQuery, ext.TIMESTAMP_EXT);
```

But last line return *undefined*. Also I am inspired from source example in [regl](https://github.com/stackgl/gl-conformance/blob/master/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/ext-disjoint-timer-query.html) library, but it's too sophisticated.

Comment: There are several examples [in the spec itself](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_disjoint_timer_query/)

Comment: Thanks, they have examples in js.